# Non-trivial solutions of linear equation system $Ax=0$ and "transposed" linear equation system $A^t x = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, transpose

Let $Ax = 0$ be a linear equation system. Assume that we already have a non-trivial solution $\tilde{x}$ which solves the linear equation system $A^t x = 0$ where $A^t$ is the transposed matrix of $A$.

> **Question** Is there a way of obtaining a non-trivial solution of $Ax=0$ by using $\tilde{x}$ explicitly?

I do not only want the existence of such a non-trivial solution (which is fairly easy to show by using the determinant). I would like to compute a solution directly from $\tilde{x}$. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find it interesting that if $A$ is a real matrix with $A^TA = AA^T$, then we can guarantee that $A^T \tilde x = 0$ implies that $A \tilde x = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That's interesting indeed! How does the proof for that work?

Comment: It suffices to show the following: if $A^TA = AA^T$, then it follows that $\|Ax\| = \|A^Tx\|$ for any vector $x$

Answer (score 3):

There can be no such method. In fact, we can construct an $A$ that has solutions $Ax = 0$ and $A^Ty = 0$ for any pair of vectors $x,y$.

For instance, we can use the following construction (motivated by singular value decomposition). Suppose $A$ is $m \times n$, and let $d = \min\{m,n\}$.  Let $u_1,\dots,u_{d-1}$ be a collection of orthonormal unit vectors perpendicular to $x$, and let $v_1,\dots,v_{d-1}$ be a collection of orthonormal unit vectors perpendicular to $y$.  Let $U$ be the matrix with columns $u_1,\dots,u_{d-1}$, and let $V$ be the matrix with columns $v_1,\dots,v_{d-1}$.  Then the matrix $A = VDU^T$ will satisfy $Ax = 0$ and $A^Ty = 0$ whenever $D$ is a $(d-1) \times (d-1)$ diagonal matrix.

Comment: Isn't that way $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n-1}$?

Comment: @Sudix yes, I had the dimensions of $D$ wrong; see the latest edit

Comment: Actually, I've decided to edit it further to make the construction more compact.

Comment: I like the idea of basing it off the SVD. However I'm not seeing why this shows that knowledge of an $x$ with $A^T x=0$ doesn't help us in finding an $\hat x$ with $A\hat x =0$

Comment: @Sudix the point I'm making here is that if we have the knowledge that $A^Tx = 0$, we have no way of excluding possible vectors $\hat x$ satisfying $A^T\hat x = 0$.  In other words, our solution to $Ax = 0$ gives us no information about the solutions to $A^T \hat x = 0$ (except for the fact that such a solution exists in the case where $A$ is square, as was pointed out).